# Rails check if Devise has any errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am looking for a way to check if Devise has any errors (invalid credentials etc.) for a before_action method in my ApplicationController. There is code in that method that I need only to run if Devise has no errors.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :foo

   def foo
      if !devise_errors?
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check credential errors like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :foo

  def foo
    if !devise_errors?
  end
  ..
  private

  def devise_errors?
    login_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_in)
    email = login_params.dig(:email)
    password = login_params.dig(:password)
    user = User.find_by(email: email)
    return true if user.blank?

    !user.valid_password?(password)
  end
  ..
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean sign in errors? Wouldn't you only need this in the session controller?

You could check the flash messages...

But you might be better off checking in [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/callbacks):

```
Warden::Manager.warden_callback do |user, auth, opts|
  # code 
end
```

Comment: No because I need it for sign up as well